Is the pushforward of a closed immersion ever fully-faithful at the level of Derived Categories?
Let $i: Z \rightarrow X$ be a closed immersion of schemes. Then, for any $\mathcal{O}_{Z}$-module $\mathcal{G}$, the counit of adjunction $i^{*}i_{*}\mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ is an isomorphism. This is proved for example in Stacks, tag 04CI.
Therefore, $i_{*}$ defines a fully-faithful functor $i_{*}: Mod(\mathcal{O}_{Z}) \rightarrow Mod(\mathcal{O}_{X})$ from the category of $\mathcal{O}_{Z}$-modules to the category of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules.
My question is whether there are examples where the pushforward induces a fully-faithful functor at the level of Derived Categories $i_{*}: D^{b}(Mod(\mathcal{O}_{Z})) \rightarrow D^{b}(Mod(\mathcal{O}_{X}))$?
As I am mainly care about K-Theory questions, I am more interested in knowing whether there exist examples where $i_{*}: D_{perf}^{b}(Z) \rightarrow D_{perf}^{b}(X)$ is fully-faithful? Here, $D_{perf}^{b}(X) \subseteq D^{b}(Mod(\mathcal{O}_{X}))$ is the full triangulated subcategory of perfect complexes on $X$.
An example that I am very interested in is the canonical inclusion of projective spaces
$i: \mathbb{P}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n}$. Indeed, the pullback $i^{*}$ is not fully-faithful, as $i^{*}(\mathcal{O}(k)) \cong \mathcal{O}(k)$, and $Hom_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}(\mathcal{O}(k),\mathcal{O}(l)) \ncong Hom_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}(\mathcal{O}(k),\mathcal{O}(l))$ for dimension reasons . But I think asking whether the pushforward is fully-faithful at the level of Derived Categories is a much more interesting question, and I would be interested to learn of a proof either way.
Any help/pointing to references would be much appreciated.

It will almost never be fully faithful (more precisely, I suspect that if $Z$ and $X$ are of finite type over a field, it will be fully faithful iff $Z$ is a connected component of $X$.) Here's one way to see that it's not in your example of projective space: the endomorphism ring of the skyscraper sheaf at a smooth point $p\in X$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Sym}(\Omega_X|_p[1])$ (proof: use the Koszul complex). This remembers the dimension of the ambient variety $X$.

It is even not well-defined in general on perfect complexes. For example, consider $X=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Z[x]/x^2)$ and $Z\subseteq X$ defined by the ideal $(x)$.

I agree with Z.M. that probably the condition that $i_\ast$ map perfect complexes to perfect complexes is just as serious a restriction as the condition that $i_\ast$ be fully faithful. At any rate, note that the $Z$-complete objects include fully faithfully into $D(X)$. So I would think that $i_\ast$ is fully faithful iff $D(Z)$ is equivalent to the $Z$-complete objects of $D(X)$, which is basically only the case if $Z$ is also open in $X$. I'd be interested to see an example where $Z$ is closed but not open and yet $i_\ast$ is fully faithful.

An example I like to keep in mind is $i : Spec \mathbb F_p \to Spec \mathbb Z_{(p)}$. Note that $i_\ast$ is not fully faithful: its "fully faithful replacement" comes by replacing $D(\mathbb F_p)$ with $D(\mathbb Z_{(p)})^\wedge_p$, which is basically more like $D(\mathbb Z_p)$. You might have better luck motivically.

@TimCampion mapping perfect complexes to perfect complexes holds in most cases of interest, namely morphisms between smooth varieties. In that case, perfect complexes are the same as bounded complexes with coherent cohomology.

Yes, I should have mentioned that I have the example of a regular embedding in mind. In this case, perfect complexes are mapped to perfect complexes.

Thank you everyone for your comments. I appreciate your time on this.

It essentially is "never" fully faithful. In your question, you implicitly assume that $i_*$ preserves perfect complexes - this is a restriction, but not as severe as fully faithfulness (e.g. it is satisfied if $Z$ is locally cut out by a regular sequence).
If this is so and if $i_*$ is fully faithful, then also $i_*:D_{qcoh}(Z)\to D_{qcoh}(X)$ is fully faithful (say $X,Z$ are qcqs).
In that case, a precise statement of "almost never" could be :
Fact: if $i_*$ is fully faithful, then the ideal sheaf $I$ defining $Z$ inside $X$ satisfies $I \otimes^L_{O_X} I\simeq I$. In particular, $I^2= I$.
For example, if $Z,X$ are noetherian this will imply that $X\cong Z\coprod U$ as schemes.
Proof: If $i_* : QCoh(Z)\to QCoh(X)$ is fully faithful, then so is $QCoh(Z\cap U)\to QCoh(U)$ for every open $U\subset X$, so the claim is local and we may reduce to $X$ being affine, say $X=Spec(A)$ and $Z= Spec(A/I)$.
In that case, $i^*i_* (A/I) = A/I\otimes^L_A A/I$ and the counit being an equivalence at $A/I$ is therefore equivalent to $A/I$ being derived idempotent over $A$ which is equivalent to $I\otimes^L_A I = I$, as claimed.
This does happen, e.g. if $A\to A/I$ is a surjection of perfect $\mathbb F_p$-algebras, but in the noetherian case (more generally if $I$ is finitely generated) this implies that $I= (e)$ for some idempotent $e$ which gives the claimed decomposition statement. So this is clearly false for inclusions of projective space, and things like $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb F_p$, etc.

Thank you Maxime for your answer. As I mentioned above, I had regular embeddings in mind, but even then, I had the feeling that in most cases, the answer would be no. Thank you for making this intuition more rigorous.
